# vs code not showing result in usual black pop up output screen

Tags: c, output, visual-studio-code

I can see my code being executed in the terminal window but the output screen does not pop up when I hit run . The output window on the console shows running and then done but the black screen with the result does not pop up like it used to before.I might have changed some settings in vscode but now I can't find the right one to change.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons. I'm afraid the changes you've applied caused this but no worries I suggest going over your project settings and VSCode's settings.
Check out these two links:

[VS Code settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

[C / CPP Config](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

P.S. I'm suggesting the second link based on your C tag.

Check your debug window too:

Menu -> Debug Console
or
Ctrl+Shift+Y.

Comment: thanks a lot that was great help!! : )